# I can't install rust on my mac

Tags: macos, installation, rust

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

I did installed `brew install curl-openssl` but still I cant install rust.

When I download this script in browser and run it i get:

```
bash rustup-init.sh 
info: downloading installer
Warning: Not enforcing strong cipher suites for TLS, this is potentially less secure
Warning: Detected OS X platform older than 10.13
Warning: Not enforcing TLS v1.2, this is potentially less secure
curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
rustup: command failed: downloader https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-apple-darwin/rustup-init /var/folders/zk/wntqfhrd2qggp08_xk79fz7m0000gq/T/tmp.yeOnuwee/rustup-init x86_64-apple-darwin
```

Comment: Try updating to current macOS. It's free. You seem to be on a version that's at least 4 years old, and the errors suggest your old macOS version is making it difficult to support the modern security required by the static.rust-lang.org server. The Mac ecosystem generally doesn't bother supporting obsolete macOS versions very well. You have to keep up to date.

Comment: Here is the problem.
I can'b because I am working on old mac. I have El Capitan here.